# How can I type the "EE" character?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking to type the "EE" character, the one that means "* 10^{x}" -- I'm trying to represent what might be typed on a Ti-84 calculator....

Comment: I think we might need a picture of this!

Comment: @Joseph: http://www.eaglefonts.com/fp/charmap.php?font=../data/media/145/Ti83Pluspc.ttf&color=c003a5&bgcolor=FFFFFF == The 6th character over on the bottom right. Except there would need to be 2 "e"s in that picture. (The TI display shows a single E, while on the keyboard there are two es, http://faculty.kutztown.edu/mitsuma/ti/tips/keypad/ti84.html -- the second function (in blue) right above the comma key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve never seen it written as “EE” but how about something like this?

```
\newcommand*\EE[1]{\ensuremath{\text{\textsc{e}}#1}}
```

Then you can write something like the following:

```
One googol is $1\EE{100}$
```

(Requires `amsmath`.)

Comment: You're right -- it does look better as a single E. I changed the macro slightly -- added a `\small` into the part with the `E` so that it appears shorter than the numbers, as it does on the TI display. `\newcommand\EE[1]{\ensuremath{\text{\small \textsc{e}}#1}}`

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing from my hazy recollection of TI calculators and their manuals (really just a stab in the dark, mind you) that you might be after something like this:

[image]

If so, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand*\EE{\textsf{\raise.2ex\hbox{[\kern-.12em{\lower.2ex\hbox{E\kern-.05em E}}\kern-.095em]}}}
\begin{document}
  Press the \EE{} button to enter orbit now.
\end{document}
```

You'll probably need to magnify your pdf reader View to see how it renders on the page (or just print it out to see for certain). If this is what you wanted (did I mention I'm only guessing?), it'll probably need some tweaking to make it better match the fonts in your LaTeX doc.